# Matrix display from a SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, matrix

Does anyone know how to create a matrix display from a database table?
I'm using ASP.NET C# and the database is SQL Server 2008.

The table looks like this.

[image]

I would like the matrix to look like this or similar.

[image]

Comment: similar question to pivot table:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069677/pivot-table-in-c

Answer (score 1):

use TSQL pivot

```
create table table1
(
    serverName varchar(30),
    app varchar(50)
);
go

insert table1 (serverName , app) values ('server1' , 'app A');
insert table1 (serverName , app) values ('server2' , 'app A');
insert table1 (serverName , app) values ('server2' , 'app B');
insert table1 (serverName , app) values ('server3' , 'app B');
insert table1 (serverName , app) values ('server1' , 'app C');
insert table1 (serverName , app) values ('server3' , 'app C');
go

create procedure GetPivotTable
as begin
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders = 
  COALESCE(@PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + cast(t.serverName as varchar) + ']' ,
  '[' + cast(t.serverName as varchar)+ ']')
FROM (select distinct serverName from table1) t


DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
select * from
(select  app, serverName from table1)  sourceTable
pivot
(
    count(serverName) for serverName in (' + @PivotColumnHeaders + ')
) pivottable
'
EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL)
end

go

exec GetPivotTable
```

Comment: edited to handle any number of servers and apps. You can put it into store procedure for easier integration with your asp.net  code

Comment: in your asp.net code , you can just call the stored procedure GetPivotTable with ado.net to get the pivot table .

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Both look interesting. I'll have to look into pivot tables a bit more as I've not used them before.

Comment: I've used your example of a TSQL query to create a pivot table and it it working great, but at the moment I have 1's and 0's in the grid where I would really like to replace them with images (as in the picture I posted). My gridview is set to auto generate the columns because I've no idea what the column names will be for each query. Do you know how I can change the 1's and 0's to images?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here would be to pull the data out in exactly the format you have it, into a List of entities (at its simplest):

```
public class ServerApplicationRelationship
{
   public string Server{get;set;}
   public string Application{get;set;}
}
```

And create yourself a custom control which renders an HTML table using the `List<ServerApplicationRelationship>` as its datasource.

It should be pretty easy to render that table from the data provided.

If you *really* want to pull the data out in that shape from sql, you could use a query such as

```
select application,
          case when exists(select 1 from example where application=ex.application and server='server 1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as [server 1],
          case when exists(select 1 from example where application=ex.application and server='server 2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as [server 2],
          case when exists(select 1 from example where application=ex.application and server='server 3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as [server 3]
    from yourTable ex
    group by application
```